# Adding new website as multiwebsite under existing drupal website

Tags: multi-sites

I have an existing Drupal website. I want to add a new website as a sub website under the existing website. I want both websites to share single database / modules.

I googled about it but didn't get use full information about.

Can anyone please explain how to add a new website as a child website of existing Drupal website?

Thanks

Comment: Which version  you are working with D7 or D8?

Answer (score 2):

[Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) modules will be your best bet. It will allow you to use same codebase and database for all your sites. You will also have an option to push content to a specific site if need be.

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites